# ClassNotFoundException for class in same package

Tags: java, exception, reflection

I am working on a project and I am running my class (call it Foo.java). I'm using the reflections Class.forName(str) where str = "Bar.java". Foo.java and Bar.java are in the same package (I'm running for testing) but I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the fully-qualified name for the class (incl. packages)

see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)